# problem calling aspx server method from javascript with jquery

Tags: asp.net, jquery

hi i'm trying to call a method in the code behind from javascript with jquery but it's doesn't work so i need help because.

**This is the javascript method**

```
function saveMap() {

if (confirm("Esta seguro de guardar el mapa?")) {
    alert("Estas en el centro:" + map.getCenter().toString() + "Con zoom: " + map.getZoom().toString());
    var mapData = new Array(map.getCenter().lat().toString(),
                            map.getCenter().lng().toString(),
                            "Esto es una prueba",
                            map.getZoom().toString());
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "SaveMap.aspx/saveMapData",
        data:"{mapData: '"+ map.getCenter().lat().toString() +"'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: response
    });    
}
}
```

**This is server method**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public bool saveMapData(string mapData) 
    {           
        if( ( mapData != null ) && ( mapData.Length < 0) )
        {
            throw new Exception("El centro y el zoom no deben ser nulos");
        }

        try
        {
            crearConexion();
            SqlCommand _sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [AtentoMIG].[dbo].[Mapa]"
                                                                              + "([latitud]"
                                                                              + ",[longitud]"
                                                                              + ",[nombre]"
                                                                              + ",[zoom])"
                                                     + "VALUES"
                                                                              + "('" + mapData[0] + "'"
                                                                              + ",'" + mapData[1]
                                                                              + ",'" + mapData[2]
                                                                              + "," + mapData[3] + "')", _sqlConexion);
            _sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            _sqlConexion.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            throw new Exception("Ocurrio un problema insertando la informacion en la base de datos");
        }
        finally 
        {
            _sqlConexion.Close();
        }

    }
```

Thank's for your help

Comment: By not working, what do you mean by that?  Throwing exception?  No response updated?  Does Success callback get called?  Also add a failure callback and see what error is coming back.

Comment: @Brian don't get to the server side method

Comment: Is `SaveMap.aspx/saveMapData` the correct url?. Try using a tool like [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see what the server response is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve the problem with only two changes in my code behind

```
 [WebMethod()] //this line change
 public static bool saveMapData(string mapData) // this line
{           
    if( ( mapData != null ) && ( mapData.Length < 0) )
    {
        throw new Exception("El centro y el zoom no deben ser nulos");
    }

    try
    {
        crearConexion();
        SqlCommand _sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [AtentoMIG].[dbo].[Mapa]"
                                                                          + "([latitud]"
                                                                          + ",[longitud]"
                                                                          + ",[nombre]"
                                                                          + ",[zoom])"
                                                 + "VALUES"
                                                                          + "('" + mapData[0] + "'"
                                                                          + ",'" + mapData[1]
                                                                          + ",'" + mapData[2]
                                                                          + "," + mapData[3] + "')", _sqlConexion);
        _sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        _sqlConexion.Close();
        return true;
    }
    catch (SqlException)
    {
        throw new Exception("Ocurrio un problema insertando la informacion en la base de datos");
    }
    finally 
    {
        _sqlConexion.Close();
    }

}
```

of the rest are the same there's no problem with the url or the json data. But thanks to all anyway

Answer (score 2):

Web methods on a page must be static:

Change:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public bool saveMapData(string mapData)
```

To:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static bool saveMapData(string mapData)
```

Also make sure the ScriptManager has `EnablePageMethods="true"` set.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the `.stringify()` method of the `JSON2.js` include to make sure my JSON is correct, but you might try changing your data line to this :

```
data:'{"mapData": "'+ map.getCenter().lat().toString() +'"}',
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling it using the ASP.NET javascript functions, they are automatically created by the ASP.NET runtime and it works well for me

MyNameSpace.MyClass.saveMapData(mapData, fnSaveMapData_Success, fnSaveMapData_Error);